# iOS/iPadOS e-mail client that would sync my IMAP credentials across multiple devices

Tags: ios, email, synchronization, imap

I have several work e-mail accounts that I need to monitor. I would like to simplify/automate setting up each on a new device, as well as keeping devices in sync. I'm looking for an iOS/iPadOS application.

I would imagine an app that uses either my master account or iCloud drive to sync the credentials across the devices. Something similar to the [Panic Sync](https://panic.com/sync/) feature.

I have tried searching on Google, but it confuses what I want with syncing actual account contents, and shows me irrelevant results, while what I want is syncing the account credentials instead. Couldn't find many results [on this site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios+email) either.

Please let me know if you know something that fits the description.

(My last resort, I guess would be setting up e-mail collection from the external accounts inside a given mailbox, and then connecting to just that mailbox using the mailbox provider's native app (or pretty much any iOS client), but then I'm not sure if it will let me reply using those remote e-mail addresses, and whether what I reply with would be saved in the Sent folders of the respective accounts.)